# Не работает sudo apt-get update. Ubuntu 20.04 LTS как вартуальная система в VirtualBox v 6.1, основная Windows 10

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

Всем привет, я новичок в Ubuntu. Описание версий выше, не получается выполнить команду sudo apt-get update, соответственно upgrade/install тоже не работают.
Код из терминала при выполнении sudo apt-get update

```
Get:1 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease [265 kB]
Hit:2 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                      
Hit:3 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [107 kB]
Get:5 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages [718 kB]
Get:6 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages [970 kB]
Get:6 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages [970 kB]
Get:6 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages [970 kB]
Get:6 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages [970 kB]
Get:6 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages [970 kB]
Get:6 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages [970 kB]
Get:6 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages [970 kB]
Get:6 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages [970 kB]
Get:6 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages [970 kB]
Get:15 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe i386 Packages [4 642 kB]
Get:16 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe Translation-en [5 124 kB]
Err:8 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
  Hash Sum mismatch
  Hashes of expected file:
   - Filesize:2124681 [weak]
   - SHA256:8e0086c5bcd5b0dbb103a52f84d3a66b30c93a9c8a410efaa0c36292f268fe94
   - SHA1:eed9b3fe857e8110e81234e355959ef77eb0b760 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:c4683d85bab6e0b0ddd11ab41fab2524 [weak]
  Hashes of received file:
   - SHA256:59d90785f9ee48c2d6972abfbe0e9c01b4d0b85c2d6d3933e8dbc8fec9f7ead4
   - SHA1:eed9b3fe857e8110e81234e355959ef77eb0b760 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:c4683d85bab6e0b0ddd11ab41fab2524 [weak]
   - Filesize:2124681 [weak]
  Last modification reported: Thu, 23 Apr 2020 11:35:42 +0000
  Release file created at: Thu, 23 Apr 2020 17:33:17 +0000
Get:17 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [3 603 kB]
Err:17 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
  
Get:18 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [265 kB]
Get:19 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse i386 Packages [74,7 kB]
Get:20 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse amd64 Packages [144 kB]
Get:21 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse Translation-en [104 kB]
Get:22 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [48,4 kB]
Get:23 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata [9 136 B]
Get:24 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages [127 kB]
Get:25 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main i386 Packages [44,1 kB]
Get:26 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main Translation-en [46,2 kB]
Get:26 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main Translation-en [46,2 kB]
Get:26 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main Translation-en [46,2 kB]
Get:26 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main Translation-en [46,2 kB]
Get:26 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main Translation-en [46,2 kB]
Get:26 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main Translation-en [46,2 kB]
Get:26 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main Translation-en [46,2 kB]
Get:26 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main Translation-en [46,2 kB]
Get:26 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main Translation-en [46,2 kB]
Get:26 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main Translation-en [46,2 kB]
Get:26 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main Translation-en [46,2 kB]
Get:37 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [1 732 B]
Get:38 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [1 172 B]
Get:39 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse Translation-en [540 B]
Get:40 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata [116 B]
Fetched 15,1 MB in 2s (7 825 kB/s)                                
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch store:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ru.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal_main_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.xz  Hash Sum mismatch
   Hashes of expected file:
    - Filesize:2124681 [weak]
    - SHA256:8e0086c5bcd5b0dbb103a52f84d3a66b30c93a9c8a410efaa0c36292f268fe94
    - SHA1:eed9b3fe857e8110e81234e355959ef77eb0b760 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:c4683d85bab6e0b0ddd11ab41fab2524 [weak]
   Hashes of received file:
    - SHA256:59d90785f9ee48c2d6972abfbe0e9c01b4d0b85c2d6d3933e8dbc8fec9f7ead4
    - SHA1:eed9b3fe857e8110e81234e355959ef77eb0b760 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:c4683d85bab6e0b0ddd11ab41fab2524 [weak]
    - Filesize:2124681 [weak]
   Last modification reported: Thu, 23 Apr 2020 11:35:42 +0000
   Release file created at: Thu, 23 Apr 2020 17:33:17 +0000
E: Failed to fetch http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/universe/dep11/by-hash/SHA256/25f05d5ab28ffd6bdb57ab80b34ecee249c3783fbd893a2338d0b848ed389882  
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Пробовал менять ссылки на зеркала представленные на [сайте](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors)

Очищал пакеты, проверял пинг на "nameserver 8.8.8.8", пинг есть, интернет на виртуалке есть, но команда никак не выполняется, при изменении ссылок ошибки могут меняться, но никогда не доходит до конца. Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Вторая ссылка из google поска. Чтобы устранить ошибку несоответствия хэш-суммы, нам нужно удалить загруженную информацию о репозитории из каталога /var/lib/apt/lists/.

Для этого мы будем использовать команду rm -rf.

$ sudo rm —rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

Comment: Удалял и этой командой и другими которые нагуглил, все еще безрезультатно, папка  /var/lib/apt/lists/ пустая, ошибки все те же при выполнении update

Comment: попробовал удалить еще раз с помощью "sudo rm —rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*" поменял ссылки на зеркало яндекса, результат тот же